# How to handle utf-8 characters in R

Tags: r, nlp, utf

I am  trying to analyze some tweets and am new to text mining. After basic pre-processing my output is:

```
> `head(tweet_corpus[[1]]$content)`
[1] "user father dysfunct selfish drag kid dysfunct run"                                          
[2] "user user thank lyft credit use caus offer wheelchair van pdx disapoint getthank"            
[3] "bihday majesti"                                                                              
[4] "model love u take u time urã°âÿâ“â± ã°âÿâ˜â™ã°âÿâ˜âžã°âÿâ‘â„ã°âÿâ‘â…ã°âÿâ’â¦ã°âÿâ’â¦ã°âÿâ’â¦"
[5] "factsguid societi now motiv"                                                                 
[6] "huge fan fare big talk leav chao pay disput get allshowandnogo"
```

And noticed these characters:

```
> ã°âÿâ“â± ã°âÿâ˜â™ã°âÿâ˜âžã°âÿâ‘â„ã°âÿâ‘â…ã°âÿâ’â¦ã°âÿâ’â¦ã°âÿâ’â¦
```

According to a I read, blog these are UTF-8. I tried to handle it using:

```
raw_tweets$tweet <- iconv(raw_tweets$tweet, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub="")
```

But got this exception:

```
Error in iconv(raw_tweets$tweet, "ASCII", "UTF-8", sub = "") : 
  embedded nul in string: '#model   i love u take with u all the time in urC\003B0C\002E8C\002b\0\034C\002B1!!! C\003B0C\002E8C\002K\034C\002b\004"C\003B0C\002E8C\002K\034C\002E=C\003B0C\002E8C\002b\0\030C\002b\0\036C\003B0C\002E8C\002b\0\030C\002b\0&C\003B0C\002E8C\002b\0\031C\002B&C\003B0C\002E8C\002b\0\031C\002B&C\003B0C\002E8C\002b\0\031C\002B&'
```

What are these codes and how can I handle these?  Are there any rule of thumb to handle such unstructured text?

Comment: explore here a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embedded+nul+%5Br%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some non- ASCII characters in my tweet.
Using this code

```
tweet_corpus= tm_map(tweet_corpus, function(x) iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))
```

I was able to solve the issue.